# jquery toggle - prevent sequential toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with class agg-drop, whose items have a class name sortedli. These items have 2 toggle states. I clone these items using .clone(true), which adds the item to a list with class name 'all-drop'. Items in this list have 3 toggle states. Now if I were to toggle the item in the new cloned list, the first two clicks do nothing, presumably because it is going through the toggle functions sequentially and the toggles are dependent on class names. Is there anyway to prevent this?

```
$(".sortedli").toggle(function(){
    if( $(this).parent().hasClass('agg-drop') ){
          $(this).css("background","orange");
    }},
    function(){
    if( $(this).parent().hasClass('agg-drop') ){
          $(this).css("background","yellow");
    }},
    function(){
    if( $(this).parent().hasClass('all-drop') ){
          $(this).css("background","red");
    }},
    function(){
    if( $(this).parent().hasClass('all-drop') ){
          $(this).css("background","green");
    }},
        function(){
    if( $(this).parent().hasClass('all-drop') ){
          $(this).css("background","blue");
    }}
);
```

Comment: could you pls share jsfiddle for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
$(".sortedli").toggle(function(){
    if( $(this).parent().hasClass('agg-drop') ){
          $(this).css("background","orange");
    }},
    function(){
    if( $(this).parent().hasClass('agg-drop') ){
          $(this).css("background","yellow");
    }
}).toggle(function(){
    function(){
    if( $(this).parent().hasClass('all-drop') ){
          $(this).css("background","red");
    }},
    function(){
    if( $(this).parent().hasClass('all-drop') ){
          $(this).css("background","green");
    }},
        function(){
    if( $(this).parent().hasClass('all-drop') ){
          $(this).css("background","blue");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in your assumption that it's going through the toggle list sequentially.  This is also why the original `li` changes twice and then does nothing 3 times.  What you want to do is attach a separate toggle event after you clone the `ul`

This is what I imagine your code looks like currently: (http://jsfiddle.net/QGxRK/2/)

```
$(function() {
    $(".sortedli").toggle(function(){
        if( $(this).parent().hasClass('agg-drop') ){
              $(this).css("background","orange");
        }},
        function(){
        if( $(this).parent().hasClass('agg-drop') ){
              $(this).css("background","yellow");
        }},
        function(){
        if( $(this).parent().hasClass('all-drop') ){
                  $(this).css("background","red");
        }},
        function(){
            if( $(this).parent().hasClass('all-drop') ){
              $(this).css("background","green");
        }},
            function(){
        if( $(this).parent().hasClass('all-drop') ){
              $(this).css("background","blue");
        }}
    );

    var allDrop = $('.agg-drop').clone(true);
    allDrop.removeClass('agg-drop').addClass('all-drop');
    allDrop.insertAfter('.agg-drop');
});
```

This is more what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/QGxRK/3/

```
$(function() {
    $(".sortedli").toggle(function(){
        if( $(this).parent().hasClass('agg-drop') ){
              $(this).css("background","orange");
        }},
        function(){
        if( $(this).parent().hasClass('agg-drop') ){
              $(this).css("background","yellow");
        }}
    );

    var allDrop = $('.agg-drop').clone(); //Don't need to clone the events
    allDrop.removeClass('agg-drop').addClass('all-drop');
    allDrop.insertAfter('.agg-drop');

    allDrop.find('.sortedli').toggle(function(){
            if( $(this).parent().hasClass('all-drop') ){
                  $(this).css("background","red");
            }
        },
        function(){
        if( $(this).parent().hasClass('all-drop') ){
                  $(this).css("background","green");
            }
        },
        function(){
            if( $(this).parent().hasClass('all-drop') ){
                  $(this).css("background","blue");
            }
        });
});
```